# How to assign [(ngModel)] to custom multiple select with 'selected' options with Angular and Materialize css?

Tags: angular, materialize

I have a following bit of code:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
         <select name="uniqueName" [(ngModel)]="model.servicesIds"  multiple>
             <ng-container *ngFor="let service of services">
                    <option *ngIf="isServiceInExistingServices(service.id, object)" selected [value]="service.id"> {{service.name}} </option>
                    <option *ngIf="!isServiceInExistingServices(service.id, object)" [value]="service.id"> {{service.name}} </option>
             </ng-container>
        </select>
    <label></label>
</div>
```

It is placed within table row in a cell. Its purpose is to display select list with options. Some of them, are preselected based on the condition inside *ngIf. Everything works fine - until I add [(ngModel)]. Without it tough, preselected options have checked checkboxes, but they are not send to external API, due to the missing ngModel. On the other hand, when I add it, selected ids are beeing binded, but - those values which satisfy condition - does not have any checkbox checked, unless I click them, but that's not the case, because also I want to see preselected ones.

Does anyone have a clue what am I doing wrong on this one ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div class="input-field col s12">
         <select name="uniqueName" [(ngModel)]="model.servicesIds"  multiple>
                    <option *ngFor="let service of services" [selected]="service.selected" [value]="service.id"> {{service.name}} </option>
        </select>
    <label></label>
</div>
```

If you want multiple items to be checked..please add a field in your services -> {selected: true}. So for the initial data binding the objects with {selected: true} will be automatically checked and {selected: false} will be unchecked.

Comment: Thank you for help, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work.   I assigned additional field to service as follows:  this.services[0]['selected'] = true; I can see the field when I check it in console, but still - no checked checkbox.

Comment: That's still not the case. I've tried with [selected]="service.selected", without [], just selected, [selected],[selected]="true", selected="true". Problem must be somewhere else..